# Copy each list item to another list item attribut

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

Is there an easy way, and most importantly, more optimized to do the fowling code:

```
class Chair{
    int numberOfLegs=4;
}

class House{
    Chair chair;
    String name="My Home";
}

// add chairs to each house
IList<Chair> chairs = new List<Chair>(10); // let us imagine that we have 10 different chairs...

// Code to replace:
IList<House> houses = new List<House>(chairs.Count());
for (int i = 0; i < houses.Count(); i++){
    houses[i].chair = chairs[i]
}
```

Comment: The "Code to replace" would not succeed because the list is initially empty.

Comment: That code are just for you understand the problem. Imagine that we've a list of 10 chairs :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My own suggestion it is replacing the `for` with `Linq`

```
// Code to replace:
IList<Homes> homes = chairs.Select(c => new Home{ Chair = c}).ToList();
```

Is it faster than the old code?

Do you have a better idea? Maybe using `chairs.AsParallel`?

Comment: +1 - straight to the point and much cleaner. tho, it doesn't of course correlate between the 2 structures in the main OP (i.e. this will work fine in isolation, but not if the 2 structures are defined seperately and need to interact in some way)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Can you be more clear @jimtollan? Are you talking about bipolar relationships?

Comment: hey again - i was referring to the fact that this will of course work for the example that you created, but will not scale out to a situation where you have a list of chairs and a seperate list of house.